# standard garden tap size (US)

Tags: pipe, taps

I am building a garden irrigation system which is directly connected to a tap. In Europe the garden taps are usually BSP 3/4" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Pipe). It would be great to have it compatible to the US, therefore I am wondering if you use the same system or what is a standard garden tap thread over there?

Any clues or just stating what you have in your garden would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the U.S. the standard is simply called Garden Hose Thread or GHT,. It's a 3/4" straight thread with a coarse thread pitch and is not compatible with the BSP which is a finer thread pitch.[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! For design purposes I would need: minor/major diameter of the thread for the internal and external threads respectively, ideally also tolerances for all 4 values... Could you guide me where to find that?

Answer (score 1):

The US uses 3/4" straight thread, with 11.5 threads per inch according to [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_hose)

Answer (score 0):

http://catalog.tapcotaps.com/item/all-categories/popular-special-taps-right-hand-/72518
From Tapco taps.  The reason no one can find GHT taps.. is because that's the thread name.. the TAP name is National Hose Thread 3/4  11 1/2 NH  The link is for the Best.. too expensive, buy one from china. Remember that it's a meaty 3/4" hand tap so breaking it will be horrifying, buy a good one .. :)